Quantum Coherence
Coherence is a term frequently used in quantum mechanics. However, I struggle to get the bigger picture. In fact, it seems like some definitions contradict each other. Could someone provide a basic overview, briefly addressing the following questions:

What is coherence in quantum mechanics?

What is a coherent state? (Is it just an eigenstate of the ladder operators?)

What is a coherent superposition?

Is every pure state a coherent state and every mixed state an incoherent state?

Can a single particle be in a coherent state, or only an ensemble (as coherence only makes sense when you have several phases)?



This phys SE website does not like lists of multiple questions in a single post, here you five, and it may get closed asking for a rewrite.

Also, you should provide what you understand of "coherent".
